# How can I find matching values from two tables?

Tags: c#, sql, sqlite

I have a question about how to find collections of values from one table that match some values from another table.

Here's my code snippet:

```
public async Task<List<TableB>> GetTableBResults(string vCode, string number)
{
    var tableARepo = DependencyResolver.Get<IRepository<DBTableA>>();
    var TableBRepo = DependencyResolver.Get<IRepository<DBTableB>>();
    var tableAQuery = string.Format("SELECT * FROM DBTableA WHERE Identifier = '{0}'",
        number);

    List<DBTableA> tableA = await tableARepo.QueryAsync(tableAQuery);


    if (tableA != null)
    {
        //Find all tableB records with info from Identifier
        //And then do a distinct on BusinessName and return those results

        foreach (var item in DBTableA)
        {
            var TableBQuery = String.Format("SELECT *" +
                            "FROM[DBTableB] INNER JOIN DBTableA" +
                            "ON  DBTableB.Code = {0}" +
                            "AND DBTableB.HouseNo = {1}" + 
                            "AND DBTableB.BusinessName = {2}" +
                            "AND DBTableB.VCode = {3}",
                            item.Code, item.HouseNo, item.FirstName, vCode); 

            List<DBTableB> tableB = await TableBRepo.QueryAsync(TableBQuery);

            if (tableBs != null)
            {
                return tableBs.Select(_ => new TableB
                {
                    BoroCode = _.BoroCode,
                    Code = _.Code,
                    HouseNo = _.HouseNo,
                    Date = _.Date,
                    BusinessName = _.BusinessName,
                }).ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                return new List<TableB>();
            }
        }

    }
    return new List<TableB>();
}
```

Here are the entities:

```
public class DBTableA
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int DBTableAKey { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [Indexed]
    public Int64 Identifier { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [Indexed]
    public int? HouseNo { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public class DBTableB
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int DBTableBKey { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [Indexed]
    public string BoroCode { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [Indexed]
    public int Code { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [Indexed]
    public string HouseNo { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string BusinessName { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    [Indexed]
    public string VCode { get; set; }
}
```

Basically, using Identifier from TableA, I want to get all matches rows from Table A where Identifier is equal to the number passed in. Then, do a compare where select fields from that tableA set match same values in TableB set
but I'm not sure how to set up the logic, I added my attempt above.

I mean I just want to return the values from Table B that matches the parameters I want to check/match in the sql query above if any. How can I improve my code above to make return the correct values?

EDIT:

Here is some mock data:

`Identifier: 123` (only in TableA: grab Code, HouseNo, FirstName that have Identifier 123)

Then match those from Table A with values from Table B where the values are the same like the sample values below:

```
Code = 456
HouseNo = 34
BusinessName = 'Bar, Foo' 

VCode = 'E4T' (passed in to method)
```

Return TableB row(s) that match the above info.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you would want a left join, rather than inner join.  That way you return all of Table A even if there isn't a match in Table B.

Comment: Please provide sample data and the desired result.

Comment: I only want to return results for Table B if there is a match. Otherwise, return nothing.

Comment: @PM77-1 I edited my post. Does that help?

Comment: Your SQL does not look right. Have you tested the code? When you write `ON  DBTableB.Code = {0}` You're not comparing fields from tableA with tableB. If you already know and have the items in TableA then why do you need a join. Why don't you just run a simple select query comparing the values from the item? I think you're over doing it.

Comment: The parameters for your TableBQuery could be causing you a problem as well. It looks like your dynamically building a SQL statement as a string then passing the string to a function that will execute the statement for you. The statement you're assigning to TableBQuery is not going to return anything because the string values are not quoted. Re-write so that things like businessName, which you have declared to be a string, are surrounded by quotes like this DBTableB.BusinessName = \"{2}\"" and so on...

Comment: Is there a particular reason you aren't using LINQ?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use LINQ to handle this query:

```
var ans = (from a in tableARepo
           where a.Identifier == number
           join b in tableBRepo on new { a.Code, HouseNo = a.HouseNo.ToString(), a.FirstName, VCode = vCode } equals new { b.Code, b.HouseNo, FirstName = b.BusinessName, b.VCode }
           select b).ToList();
return ans;
```

Comment: I tried the approach above but I get:  Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'DBTableA.  'Where' not found and  'DBTableB' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Sorry, you need the sqlite LINQ provider and you must query against the tables, not the class types. I modified the answer slightly, but I don't know if you can use LINQ against `IRepository`. Perhaps you will need more LINQ to SQLite knowledge.